# Why do div get scrolled when input is selected in tizen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tizen-web-app

I have a tizen web application which has multiple input field. When user clicks on any input that div scrolls to the bottom and the input drawers comes up. So the user can't see the input field. How do I prevent this?

I tried using this:

```
$('input').bind('focusin focus', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It doesn't work.

Edit:
Here is a sample part:

```
<div class="ui-page" id="">
    <div class="ui-header">
        <h1 class="ui-title">Header</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-content" id="history">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><span>Input 1:</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="tel" id="input1" style="background-color: #d1d1d1;">
            </li>
            <li><span>input 2:</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" id="input2" style="background-color: #d1d1d1;">
            </li>

            <li><span>Input 3</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="number" id="input3" style="background-color: #d1d1d1;">
            </li>
        </ul>

        <input class="ui-btn" type="button" onclick="done_click()" value="Done">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can u plz share HTML code

Comment: @RRR sample added in edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

The following code will autoscroll to your input on focus.

```
$('input').bind('focusin focus', function(e){
    var $input = $(this);
    $('html,body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $input.offset().top } , '500', 'swing');
});
```

I would even set an `offset - 25`, to provide a good visibility and it creates some space on the top. You may adjust this your way later.

If this does not work, try setting a timeout: eg.

```
$('input').bind('focusin focus', function(e){
    var $input = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('html,body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $input.offset().top } , '500', 'swing');
    }, 345);
});
```